# random function in scheme

Tags: scheme, racket

I am trying to get a random string from a list of strings in scheme.
Example List ( "this" "that" "today" "yesterday")
So based on length of the list a random number is created and that word is output. But keep getting error!

I tried it like this:

```
;; produces random number that should be input to the random-function

(define (random-num list)

(random-function ((random (length (list))) list)))

;; loops the number of times till random number is 0 and outputs the list value

(define (random-function num list )
  (cond 
    [(zero? num) (car list)]
    [else (random-function (- num 1) (cdr list))]))
```

Error:

```
procedure application: expected procedure, given: 
("this" "that" "today" "yesterday") (no arguments)
```

When I try to do :

```
(random-function (random (length list))
```

on the console I get a random number.

Do not understand why it is crashing here when done inside my program???

Could I do this in a better way rather than looping so many times.
In Java I would have used an array and given the position directly.
Anyway to do it in scheme too ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
(define (random-element list)
  (list-ref list (random (length list))))
```

Comment: u r awesome!! list-ref is awesome!! seems better than arrays now :)

Comment: Well, vectors are still better if you have really big lists, otherwise the difference is negligible.

Comment: Vectors are better because you can instantly jump to element `n`, whereas lists you have to start from the beginning and find your way to element `n`.

Comment: Yes, vectors are random access -- but people often overestimate the difference, and end up with vectors and inconvenient code too early.

Comment: And then there is also such a beast as a random access list,.